# java ASCII conversion

Tags: java, ascii, data-conversion

Here is part of my code:

```
 // randomly create lowercase ASCII values
 int rLowercase1 = random.nextInt(122) + 97;

 // convert ASCII to text
 System.out.print((char)rLowercase1);
```

When I run my program, it displays symbols instead of lowercase letters. Is there any way that I can fix this so that it displays lowercase letters?

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
rLowercase1 = 'a' + random.nextInt('z' - 'a' + 1);
```

Number of letters in alphabet can be calculated with `'z' - 'a' + 1` = `25 + 1` = `26`.

Since `random.nextInt(n)` will return value from range `[0; n)` - `n` is excluded - it means that you can get `'a'+0` = `'a'` as minimal value and `'a'+25` = `'z'` as max value.

In other words your range of characters is from `'a'` till `'z'` (both included).

Comment: Avoid magic numbers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad). The question is another example of why magic numbers are bad.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as:

```
int rLowercase1 = random.nextInt(26) + 97; // it will generate a-z
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only 26 lower case letters:

```
int rLowercase1 = random.nextInt(26) + 97;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the 26 unaccented Latin letters, Change 122 to 26:

```
int rLowercase1 = random.nextInt(26) + 97;
```

I think the meaning of this is a little clearer if written like this:

```
int rLowercase1 = 'a' + random.nextInt(26);
```